# Can you pass values to included files in PHP without using globals?

Tags: php, include, global-namespace

A pattern I tend to use often in PHP is setting a few globals (such as `$page`, `$user`, `$db`, etc), and then including a file which uses those globals. I've never liked the idea of using globals for this, though, so I'm looking for a better way.

The obvious solution is to define a class or function in the subfile, and call it after the file is included. There are cases where that can't work though, such as this:

```
// Add entries to a URI table from each section of the site
global $router;
$router = new VirtualFileSystem();
$sections = array('store', 'forum', 'blog');
foreach($sections as $section)
    include dirname(__FILE__) . $section . '/routing.php';

// Example contents of 'forum/routing.php'
// implicitly receive $router from caller
$router->add('fourm/topic/', 'topic.php');
$router->add('forum/topic/new/', 'new_topic.php');
// etc
```

If I tried to wrap each `routing.php` in a function and call them each with `$router` as an argument, the same function name would clash after being defined in multiple files.

I'm out of ideas. Is there a better way to pass variables to included files without polluting the global namespace?

Comment: looks like you're overcomplicating things

Comment: `global $router` won't do anything there, the scope is already global (unless this is written inside a function which we're not seeing).

Answer (score 2):

`include` and its siblings are basically just copy-paste helpers, and the code inside them shares scope with the calling block - as if you'd copy & paste it just where the `include` statement is. The sane way of using them is to think of them the same way you'd use `#include` in C or `using` in C# or `import` in Java: import some code to be referenced later on. If you have code in the included file that needs parameters, then wrap it in a function, put the parameters in the function arguments, use `include_once` at the top of the including file, and call the function with the parameters you want, wherever you need to. No globals required. As a rule of thumb, in regular operation, putting any code that "does" something (executes statements in the global scope) in an included file is best avoided IMO.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. You're not *passing* variables to included files anyway. The code that is included behaves as if it was written where the `include` statement is written. As such, you're not passing variables into the included file, the code in the file can simply use the variables that are in scope wherever the `include` statement is located.

In your case the contents of `forum/routing.php` are not really standalone code, they're code snippets that depend on a very specifically set up scope to function correctly. That's bad. You should write your includable files in a way that does not couple them to the including code. For example, you could make your Router a static class and call it statically in `forum/routing.php`:

```
require_once 'virtual_file_system.class.php';
VirtualFileSystem::add('forum/topic/', 'topic.php');
```

As long as there is a class `VirtualFileSystem` in your app, this will work, and won't pollute the namespace any more than it already is anyway.

Answer (score 1):

just isolate includes in a function:

```
function add_entries_to_router($router, $sections) {
    foreach($sections as $section)
        include dirname(__FILE__) . $section . '/routing.php';
}

$router = new VirtualFileSystem();
add_entries_to_router($router, array('store', 'forum', 'blog'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try an OOP way by making a Configuration class as a singleton and retrieving it when you need it.

You could define magic methods for __get and __set to add them to an private array var and make the constructor private.

I usually define as constant only the path to my src project in order to load class files quickly and properly (and use some SPL too).

But I agree with @tdammers about the fact that an include keep the environment variables like if you were on the caller file (the one who makes the include).